# Eclipse not passing values from build.xml file to properties file

Tags: eclipse

I have the following line on my app properties file:
**app.environment**=@ENVIRONMENT@

and this line on my build.xml file:
*<filter token="ENVIRONMENT" value="${PILTEnvironment}"/>*

and this line on my build_dev.xml:
*<property name="PILTEnvironment" value="LOCAL"/>*

So, when running the app on Eclipse Version: 2021-06 (4.20.0), Build id: 20210612-2011, **app.environment** takes "LOCAL" value, as expected,

however, when running the app on Eclipse Version: Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a), Build id: 20180405-1200, **app.environment** takes value of "@ENVIRONMENT@"

What am I missing on Eclipe Oxygen?

Any help would be very appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: What are you building? Those aren't core Eclipse build files. You need to give more details about what you are doing.

Comment: The point is, why in one Eclipse the value of ENVIRONMENT between @@ is passed but in Eclipse Oxygen that doesn't work, and the passed value is literall @ENVIRONMENT@. I even replaced @@ byt ${ } but didn't work either. Is there anything in Eclipse preferences that needs to change??

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what build.xml you are talking about. Until you tell us that there is no way to help.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, I figured it out. I was missing my C:/ant folder, now when running the servlet it understands @ENVIRONMENT@.